# How to detect if I run in an Electron AppImage in Linux?

Tags: linux, electron, appimage

I am building an electron app and I need to make a decision depending on if the app is an AppImage. The image itself is mounted in a directory, so sys.argv contains nothing that helps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the app is an AppImage, `process.env.APPIMAGE` contains the path to the .AppImage file, otherwise it is undefined.

Some of the other properties of `process.env` can be helpful, such as `APPDIR` which contains the path of the temporary directory where the actual image is mounted.

Comment: Thanks so much! That what I needed